# Calling methods from cocoapods in NativeScript

Tags: javascript, objective-c, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to implement a plugin in NativeScript which uses a pod and pod has the following methods.

```
// basic usage
[self.view makeToast:@"This is a piece of toast."];

// toast with a specific duration and position
[self.view makeToast:@"This is a piece of toast with a specific duration and position." 
            duration:3.0
            position:CSToastPositionTop];
```

the basic usage works fine like this:

```
frameModule.topmost().ios.controller.view.makeToast("sometext");
```

but when i try to send multiple parameters for specific duration and position

```
frameModule.topmost().ios.controller.view.makeToast(toastObject.text, 5.0, CSToastPositionTop);
```

I get this exception in console

> Actual arguments count: "3". Expected: "1".

How do we send multiple parameters in to call native functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I order to run native functions through JS you will have to see what methods are exposed to you.

```
TNS_TYPESCRIPT_DECLARATIONS_PATH="${pwd}/typings" tns build ios
```

The above command generates a folder with .ts files for all the modules available. The file contains the methods exposed to us which can be used in JS.

In my case to set Duration I had to use `CSToastManager.setDuration()`

For the original issue please refer to this link
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2653

Answer (score 0):

The NativeScript iOS runtime creates multiple JavaScript functions for the various argument permutations that exist natively.

I might not have the syntax perfect, but I would expect this to work:

```
frameModule.topmost().ios.controller.view.makeToastWithDurationPosition(
  "This is a piece of toast...", 3, CSToastPositionTop);
```

Comment: it didn't work. We have to see what methods are exposed in JS for us. See my answer